# install4j won't allow periods in the file name

Tags: install4j

My media file is ${compiler:app.name}-${compiler:app.version}_${compiler:app.build}

where the app.verion property will be something like 3.0 however the generated exe will have 3_0 in the filename instead of 3.0.  Is this intended and if so is there a way to disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under General Settings->Media File Options, deselect "Convert dots to underscores".